# model binding in drop down list does not returning the id of selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to bind the selected `CityName` to my model but selected items id is not binding to my model variable

My model

```
public class EmployeeModel
{            
    public string name { get; set; }
    public MyCity Cities { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Drp_city { get; set; }
}

public class MyCity
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
empmodel.Drp_city = (from s in entity.Cities
                     select new SelectListItem()
                     {
                         Text = s.CityName,
                         Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.CityId)

                     }).ToList<SelectListItem>();
```

My View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cities.CityId, Model.Drp_city)
```

I can see dropdown list of cities  but selected city id is not getting stored in model.Cities.CityId when i try to store in database( NULL is stored in database )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Cities.CityId, new SelectList(Model.Drp_city , "Text", "Value"))
```